# How to increase available memory size in GroovyConsole?

Tags: windows, groovy, jvm, groovy-console

I'm running scripts inside GroovyConsole 2.4.5 on Windows 7 64-bit and they are crashing due to out of memory error. `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` shows 247MB and my PC has 32GB RAM. What is the way to increase memory available for GroovyConsole and underlying JVM?

I tried editing `startGroovy.bat` file with:

```
set GROOVY_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Xms1g"
```

and other values, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not on Windows, so can't test, but you should be able to use `JAVA_OPTS` instead of `GROOVY_OPTS`, ie:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1G"
```

Before you run groovyConsole

Comment: For me works for both, using `GROOVY_OPTS` or `JAVA_OPTS` since java execution in `startGroovy.bat` use both: `"%JAVA_EXE%" %GROOVY_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS%...` however seems that OP has a specific problema with his configuration.

Comment: Setting environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` to `-Xmx1G` works. Unfortunately, larger values crash GroovyConsole on startup. I'm still puzzled why changes in `startGroovy.bat` file have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You're already doing correctly, edit `startGroovy.bat` and simply try with `g` lowercase, to set `GROOVY_OPTS`:

```
set GROOVY_OPTS="-Xmx1g"
```

After some tries I see the follow effect, If I use `"` to set `GROOVY_OPTS` only work with one parameter, if I want to use two parameters `-Xmx1g -Xms512m` I've to remove `"` if not it doesn't works. So you can try with:

```
set GROOVY_OPTS=-Xmx1g -Xms512m
```

Instead of

```
set GROOVY_OPTS="-Xmx1g -Xms512m"
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: I tried both upper and lower case with no effect. Oracle's docs lists both cases.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Ops... for me uppercase doesn't works, however lowercase works.

Comment: @PaulJurczak however only works with `-Xmx` parameter, if I add `-Xms` parameter the console throws an error and doesn't start.

Comment: I edited the question to lower case, which is what I'm trying now with different values and no effect.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but `set GROOVY_OPTS=-Xmx1g -Xms512m` has no effect either.

Answer (score 0):

`GROOVY_OPTS` is an internal variable used by Groovy scripts (such as `startGroovy.bat`). Even if you set the value of this variable, it will be overwritten by the scripts. The scripts do not expect anything in `GROOVY_OPTS`.

Groovy scripts, however, expect that you pass Java options for Groovy in `JAVA_OPTS`.

Therefore, use the following (without quote characters; uppercase/lowercase `G` vs `g` does not matter):

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2g -Xms1g
```